# Parallel Port Controlling using executable file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, exe

How can I control Parallel Port outputs/inputs with Batch files or other Executable File ?
     Like i say, i want to high pin number 3,4 and 7.
Please Any One Give me any idea.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft locked down I/O ports after windows 9x due to security issues but you can get usermode access to them using a special kernel mode driver found [here](http://www.embeddedtronics.com/public/Electronics/minidaq/userport/UserPort.zip). After you run that program, you can use debug to toggle pins. Debug uses Hex values so, to switch on 3,4 and 7 you'd do

```
 debug
 -o 378 02
 G
 -o 378 04
 G
 -o 378 20
 G
```

You can wrap that into a batch file or just run it from a `CMD` prompt.